# Jsoup fail to select script node for facebook html source

Tags: jsoup

I am searching a special "script" node in facebook html source, the node looks like

```
<script>require("TimeSlice").guard(function() ...
```

So I tried to find it:

```
Element scriptNode = doc.select("script:contains(require)").first();
System.out.println(scriptNode);
```

But it returns null all the time. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Did you check if the document actually contains this node via other means? Maybe the document is not fully loaded? How do you retrieve the html?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I download the html to local disk with phantomjs and open it with sublime, then I make the select statement "script:contains(require)". And this statement works well on gumbo-query (another html parser support jquery selector).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hit a known issue of Jsoup (see [SCRIPT element should provide :text() behaviors](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/190)).

SCRIPT elements are considered as data so you can't rely on `:contains` to match them.

Instead, use a work around like below:

```
Elements scriptNodes = doc.select("script");
for(Element scriptNode : scriptNodes) {
   if (scriptNode.html().startsWith("require")) {
      System.out.println(scriptNode);
   }
}
```

`scriptNode.html()` will return the content of the matched script node.

**Tested on Jsoup 1.8.3**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.